# Property of a semicyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3596317/721644) has already been asked yesterday by the user @anonymus. I tried to solve it unsuccessfully after leaving a longer comment to persuade the $OP$ to include personal thoughts in the post. Since nothing has happened up to this moment, I voted to close it and ask the same question here including my attempt.

Here it goes:

> Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral inscribed in a circle, where $|DC|<|AB|$ and $DC\nparallel AB$. Let $X$ be the intersection point of the diagonals $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{BD}$. And $Y$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $X$ on the edge $\overline{AB}$. If $XY$ bisects the angle $\measuredangle{DYC}$, prove that $\overline{AB}$ is the diameter of the (circum)circle, i.e. $ABCD$ is a semicyclic quadrilateral.

---

**My attempt:**

If $XY$ bisects $\measuredangle DYC$, then $\measuredangle DYX=\measuredangle XYC$.
$$\color{red}{\measuredangle AYD}=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle DYX=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle XYC=\color{red}{\measuredangle CYB}$$
$$\measuredangle C'YA=\measuredangle AYD$$

When drawing, I noticed that $X$ is the center of the circle inscribed in $\Delta DYC$
$$\implies\color{green}{\measuredangle CDB=\measuredangle BDY}\;\&\;\color{blue}{\measuredangle YCA=\measuredangle ACD}$$
I tried using the following:
$$\color{purple}{\Delta ABX\sim\Delta CDX}\;\&\;\Delta AXD\sim\Delta CXB$$

My reasoning is circular. 
I'm not sure if I should already assume $\color{brown}{\measuredangle{BDA}=\measuredangle{BCA}=90^{\circ}}$.

Then there's no point in stating that $BCXY$ is also a cyclic quadrilateral.

How can I continue and improve what I've written so far? Thank you in advance!

---

Update:
For all those wondering, thanks to @Blue in the comment section, I will read more on the topic: [Incircle and excircles of a triangle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle)

---

**Picture:**
[image]

Comment: While it's true that $X$ is the incenter of $\triangle DYC$, you haven't proven it. Once you do that, though, here's a path to the conclusion: Show that, as the intersection of internal bisector $AC$ and external bisectors $AB$, point $A$ must be an *excenter* of $\triangle DYC$. Consequently, $AD$ is an external bisector, making it perpendicular to internal bisector $BD$. By Thales' Theorem, $\triangle ADB$ is inscribed in a semicircle.

Comment: @Blue, I will look up for the term _excenter_. One of my main obstacles was to prove $AC$ really bisects the $\measuredangle{DCY}$. That concerns me. Thank you for guidance and helpful advices.

Comment: The way I did it was to name some angles, use trig to find the lengths of $XA$, $XB$, $XC$, $XD$, and then invoke the cyclic quad fact that $XA\cdot XC=XB\cdot XD$ to relate those angles, eventually deducing that $AC$ and $BD$ are bisectors. My work is a bit tedious, though. I'm looking for an elegant path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach that may be unnecessarily-complicated.

[image]

In the figure, $\angle BAC\cong\angle BDC$ and $\angle ABD\cong\angle ACD$, since each pairs of angles subtend the same arcs. A little angle-chasing gives $\angle YCA=90^\circ-\alpha-\theta$ and $\angle YDB=90^\circ-\beta-\theta$.

By the trigonometric form of [Ceva's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) (see an alternative below), we have
$$1 = \frac{\sin\angle CYX}{\sin\angle XYD}\cdot\frac{\sin\angle DCX}{\sin\angle XCY}\cdot\frac{\sin\angle YDX}{\sin\angle XDC} = 1\cdot\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin(90^\circ-\alpha-\theta)}\cdot\frac{\sin(90^\circ-\beta-\theta)}{\sin\alpha} \tag{1}$$
so that
$$\sin\alpha\cos(\alpha+\theta) = \sin\beta\cos(\beta+\theta) \quad\to\quad \sin(\alpha-\beta)\cos(\alpha+\beta+\theta) =  0 \tag{2}$$
Since $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\theta$ are positive and acute, we have either that $\alpha=\beta$ or $\alpha+\beta+\theta=90^\circ$. The former would make $\overline{AB}\parallel\overline{CD}$, which violates an assumption; thus, the latter holds. Substituting into the expressions for $\angle YDB$, we find this equal to $\alpha$, and is thus also equal to $\angle YDX$. This makes $\square XYAD$ a cyclic quadrilateral whose opposite angles at $Y$ and $D$ must be supplementary. The result follows. $\square$

---

**Note.** I like to throw in trigonometric Ceva whenever possible, because I don't think it gets enough attention, but it isn't necessary to get to $(2)$.

Instead, we can define, say, $x := |XY|$ and use straightforward trig to give expressions in $x$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\theta$ for the lengths of the subsegments of the diagonals of $\square ABCD$. Then, we can use the similarity $\triangle AXB\sim\triangle DXB$ (or, equivalently, the chord-chord aspect of the [Power of a Point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point#Theorems)) to write
$$|XA|\cdot|XC| = |XB|\cdot|XD| \tag{3}$$
and manipulate the result into $(2)$.

Comment: I think  the introduction of the excenter can be avoided. As soon as the fact that $X$ is the incenter is established, from $\angle XCY=\angle XBY$ the result $\angle ACB=90^\circ$ immediately follows. The idea with the trigonometric form of Ceva's Theorem is brilliant. (+1)

Comment: @user: Thanks. I guess I got a little tunnel-visioned with the angle bisector stuff. :)

Comment: One question: where was the assumption $>$ used in the derivation? Surely it is used in the figure but I do not see clearly what part of the derivation will fail in the "wrong" case.

Comment: @Blue, I do not believe the proof is unnecessarily-complicated. Instead using the trigonometric form of Ceva was a brilliant idea! The only thing I fail to understand is how $\sin\alpha\cos(\alpha+\theta)=\sin\beta\sin(90^\circ-\beta-\theta)\implies \sin(\alpha-\beta)\cos(\alpha+\beta+\theta)$...

Comment: @Dr.Mathva: Thanks for the kind words. To get the trig implication, expand the first relation. (I see that I forgot to shorten the right-hand side to $\sin\beta\cos(\beta+\theta)$.) Collect terms to give, say, $M \cos\theta+ N \sin\theta = 0$. You'll find that $M$ simplifies to $\sin(\alpha-\beta)\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ and $N$ simplifies to $-\sin(\alpha-\beta)\sin(\alpha+\beta)$. Factor-out the $\sin(\alpha-\beta)$, and the rest combines to $\cos(\alpha+\beta+\theta)$.

Comment: @user: *"where was the assumption $AB>CD$ used in the derivation?"* Excellent question! I'm actually not sure of the answer. :) I'll have to give it some thought.

Comment: After some thoughts I came to the conclusion that the assumption is superfluous. I would assume that the construction (perpendicular = bisector) is impossible for the smaller side, since it leads to contradiction (the side appears to be the diameter).